# Add HTML when a certain checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I want to add HTML to a page a certain checkbox is clicked (right now it's Reddit's 'Remember Me' checkbox, but in the future I'm want it to work with more checkboxes).  I have made this content script, but I have no idea if it's doing anything to the opened chrome tab.

```
\\content_script.js
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var inputTable = document.getElementByTagName('input');
    for(var i=0; i<inputTable.length; i++){
        if((inputTable[i].getAttribute('type')=='checkbox') && (inputTable[i].getAttribute('name')=='rem')){
                var rememberMe = inputTable[i];
        }
    }
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
                rememberMe.addEventListener('change', changeHandler);
    });
}
function changeHandler(){
    if(rememberMe.checked){
        var remTrack = chrome.extension.getURL ("rememberme.htm");
        document.body.insertBefore (remTrack, document.body.firstChild);
    }
    else{
    }
}
```

**rememberme.htm** is the html that I want to add containing the mp3 that I want to play (Will this work if the page isn't necessarily in HTML5?).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
    <title>Remember Me</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="HelloWorld.js"></script>
</head><body>
<audio autoplay loop>
  <source src="remember.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
</body></html>
```

From what I've been reading it seems like I should just make the content script call whatever javascript that I want the open chrome tab to run, but I don't know how to do this while also inserting HTML into the open chrome tab.  Any help is appreciated, and if the  tag won't work if the page is not in HTML5 then what is the easiest way to play the mp3 in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Reddit is my favorite page, I guess that Redditors should stick together, so here's your script refactored.

It appends a track with 'God Save the Queen' played by United States Navy Band to Reddit  homepage after clicking remember me button. When specifying audio source you need to give an url where the track is located, just like with images. You also don't need to add head and body, and the way you are fetching your html it is mistaken, you're actually getting only an url not html of your extension.

```
window.onload =  main();

function main() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('rem-login-main'); 
    elem = addEventListener('change',changeHandler);
}

function changeHandler () {
    var yourAudio = document.createElement('audio');
    yourAudio.src = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/de/United_States_Navy_Band_-_God_Save_the_Queen.ogg";
    yourAudio.controls = true;
    yourAudio.autoplay = true;
    var parentNode = document.getElementById('header');
    parentNode.insertBefore(yourAudio);
}
```

To test it go to Reddit, click F12, open chrome browser devtools console, within devtools go to tab sources, find tab snippets, right click, create new snippet, copy paste this code, save it, click play button on the right (it says 'run snippet' when you hover over it). If you want to make it an extension you need manifest.json.

Hope it works, don't remember to upvote or accept an answer if you find it useful.